# firebase object size: how to ignore properties with $?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire, angularjs-filter

we have an object that contains the users' notification data. how do we ignore all the firebase keys starting with $? because when calculating the size of the object with

```
.filter('keylength', function() {
return function(input) {
    if (!angular.isObject(input)) {
        throw Error("input was not an object!")
    }
    return Object.keys(input).length;
}
})
```

it returns the "wrong" number (I know it's correct, but in our case...)
The object looks like this:

```
$$conf: Object
$id: "notifications"
$priority: null
$value: null
__proto__: Object
```

the filter returns "1", it should return 0 since the object has no child nodes

Comment: I wrote an answer based on what you provided. But it's likely that you'd be better served by AngularFire's `$asArray()` method, which creates a regular array (with a `length` property) for you based on a Firebase collection.

Comment: The title of your question seems to point to yet another topic: the size of an object in Firebase. If you're after the size in number of characters, you're probably even better served by using Firebase's regular JavaScript API and `ref.on('value', function(snapshot) { console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()).length) })`

Comment: we were using $asArray but then we needed three way data binding, which doesn't seem to work with arrays

Comment: You might want to re-consider: the path you're now taking seems destined for a painful experience. I've used AngularFire arrays with three-way binding without problems (e.g. in https://github.com/puf/trenches/blob/master/app.js). If you can't get them to work, post a question with an MCVE. If you're not getting a helpful answer on that question, double check if you've really asked it in the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just filter them out in the filter.

```
.filter('keylength', function() {
  var ignoreExp = /^\$+/;
  return function(input) {
    if (!angular.isObject(input)) {
      throw Error("input was not an object!")
    }

    return Object.keys(input).filter(function(key) {
      //This is what angular does in angular.copy
      //return (key.charAt(0) !== '$' && key.charAt(1) !== '$');
      //Or just Filter out the ones that starts with any number of $
      return !ignoreExp.test(key); 
    }).length;
  }
});
```

**Demo**

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.obj = {
    $$conf: {},
    $id: "notifications",
    $priority: null,
    $$value: null,
    test:"hey"
  };
}).filter('keylength', function() {
  var ignoreExp = /^\$+/;
  return function(input) {
    if (!angular.isObject(input)) {
      throw Error("input was not an object!")
    }
 
    return Object.keys(input).filter(function(key) {
      //return (key.charAt(0) !== '$' && key.charAt(1) !== '$');
      return !ignoreExp.test(key)
    }).length;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  Length={{obj|keylength}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Object.keys` returns array, which you can then filter in any way you like:

```
return Object
    .keys(input)
    .filter(function(item) { return item.indexOf('$') != 0; })
    .length;
```

Take note that this solution is unrelated to Firebase, AngularJS or AngularFire. It is pure JavaScript.